# Error in data.py module "cannot import name 'wb'"

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Pandas has worked fine for me for years.  All of a sudden, today, I am getting this error:

```
File "C:\Users\Excel\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dautil\data.py", line 3, in <module>
    from pandas.io import wb

ImportError: cannot import name 'wb'
```

It seems like the error is coming form data.py.  Here is a screen shot.

[image]

This seemed to happen all of a sudden, and the error is triggered when I run a few different processes that call this process.  I uninstalled and re-installed pandas.  I am still getting the same error.

Comment: What version of pandas do you have? Looks like this problem: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/remote_data.html

Comment: Do you have other versions of python installed in the same env?

Comment: pd.__version__
'0.23.4'

No, I have no other versions of python installed.  I use only Python 3.6.5.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation says

> Starting in 0.19.0, pandas no longer supports pandas.io.data or
>   pandas.io.wb, so you must replace your imports from pandas.io with
>   those from pandas_datareader:

So, as per [documentation](https://pandas-datareader.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), you should be doing this:

```
from pandas.io import data, wb # becomes
from pandas_datareader import data, wb
```

Comment: Well, several pip uninstall 'whatever_package' and then pip install 'whatever_package', and then rebooting my machine seemed to fix everything.  There seemed to be some dependencies that were not getting updated during the uninstall and (re)install steps, so it took a few trial-and-error attempts to get everything straightened out.

Answer (score 0):

Even with **pandas_datareader**, the same error may happen, if this your case, then you have two solutions

for Pandas >=0.23 make sure that your pandas_datareader is > = 0.7, if for some reason you don't want to upgrade pandas_datareader to 0.7, or downgrading the pandas_datareader, then alternavly, you can do:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.core.common.is_list_like = pd.api.types.is_list_like
import pandas_datareader as web
```